# iterate over mix of single values and iterables in python

Tags: python

I'm writing a for loop in Python and I'd like to iterate over a mix of single objects and flattened lists (or tuples) of objects.

For example:

```
a = 'one'
b = 'two'
c = [4, 5]
d = (10, 20, 30)
```

I'd like to iterate over all of these in a for loop. I was thinking a syntax like this would be elegant:

```
for obj in what_goes_here(a, b, *c, *d):
  # do something with obj
```

I looked in `itertools` for `what_goes_here` and I didn't see anything, but I feel I must be missing something obvious!

The closest I found was chain but I'm wondering if anything exists that would leave my example unchanged (replacing `what_goes_here` only).

Comment: what's your iterate output?

Comment: The problem you will have is that strings are iterable, so your strings are likely to get unbundled into single characters. I think you'll probably need to write your own function for this.

Comment: ```l = [a, b, c, d]``` 
```list(itertools.chain(*[x if not isinstance(x, str) else [x] for x in l]))```

Comment: As what @AlJohri has in the list comprehension you could check for the objects type.

Comment: Or `for obj in [a, b, *c, *d]:`?

Comment: @AlJohri: `isinstance(x, str)`? Doesn't work if `b = 12` right?

Comment: @KevinGuan - You can't do that with `list`s.

Comment: @KevinGuan fixed in answer below

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Huh? Any problem with my code?

Comment: @KevinGuan he wants to replicate [a, b, *c, *d] without having to manually put asterisks everywhere

Comment: @AlJohri: Did he say that? Where? I can only see a *but I'm wondering if anything exists that would leave my example unchanged (replacing what_goes_here only)*.

Comment: @AlJohri - I don't see anything about not wanting the asterisks there. In fact, the use of those asterisks to indicate what should and should not be unpacked is the reason this question isn't a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to use Python 3.5 or higher for the expanded unpacking syntax. Put all the arguments into a container (like a `tuple`) then send that container to `itertools.chain`.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = 'one'
>>> b = 'two'
>>> c = [4, 5]
>>> d = (10, 20, 30)
>>> list(itertools.chain((a, b, *c, *d)))
['one', 'two', 4, 5, 10, 20, 30]
>>> list(itertools.chain((a, *c, b, *d)))
['one', 4, 5, 'two', 10, 20, 30]
>>> list(itertools.chain((*a, *c, b, *d)))
['o', 'n', 'e', 4, 5, 'two', 10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections, itertools

a = 'one'
b = 'two'
c = [4, 5]
d = (10, 20, 30)
e = 12

l = [a, b, c, d, e]

newl = list(itertools.chain(*[x if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str) else [x] for x in l]))
```